# Do gaps in primary key slow down queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table where `id` is the primary key and auto-incremented.

Since I have a cron job that runs once per minute (updating stats from an external API) using `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, I'm finding a lot of gaps in the `id` column.  I have one column set to be unique, obviously that's what is causing the gaps.

For example, there's only 183 rows, but I'm already at 71511 for the `id` column.

The only SELECT query I run is similar to this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE member = '123' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30`

I don't care that the number is getting high quickly and it's not used anywhere else.  I'm just trying to find out if it'll cause queries to be slower over time.

For example, if I had a table with 100,000 rows but the `id` is at a billion, would the gaps cause inserts or selects to run slower?

Comment: Nope, the `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `SELECT`, and `UPDATE` queries would not suffer any degradation.

Comment: I think this is a good question. +1

Comment: If you are creating numbers so fast, I suggest your `id` column should be `BIGINT` instead of `INT`. The latter maxes out at 2 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, I would say this isn't an issue.  However, this catches my eye:

> For example, there's only 183 rows, but I'm already at 71511 for the id column.

This is a *lot* of gaps.  The usual reasons for gaps are deletions and failed inserts (and in other databases, allocation of blocks of ids for efficiency).

You seem to understand the gaps.  You can eliminate them with some slight of hand on the inserts:

```
insert into t ( . . . )
    select . . .  --values here
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where . . .)  -- duplicate key catch here
    on duplicate key . . .;
```

You will only need the duplicate key in the event of race conditions -- the `where` will eliminate most or all of them *before* the `insert`.  This will probably eliminate all gaps.

Having to use a bigint for a table with 100,000 rows is more than inelegant.  Big integers double the size of the indexes.  They increase the amount of storage needed for a record on each page.  Increasing the size of the database increases the I/O overhead.

Answer (score 5):

No, the gaps are there **because** it's faster and easier to deal with concurrent system by calculating the unique identifier that way.

Whether the value of your auto_increment is `1` or `755131` is irrelevant for performance purposes.

Storage requirement is defined by your table, most-used storage identifier for an autoincrement is a 4-byte `int`. Whatever number you store, it takes up 4 bytes (if it can fit in 4 bytes of course).

There's a reason why gaps occur and why they aren't a problem. `Primary key` is a unique identifier. The easiest way to calculate a unique identifier is to increment a number every time you mutate the table (insert, delete).

This number is not required to be **sequential** but **unique**. MySQL uses a sequential algorithm to calculate a unique number.

Since MySQL operates with concurrency in mind, every transaction is isolated (if a transactional engine is used). If a transaction incurs a change to auto_increment but fails to be written down - the auto_increment is spent forever. There's a single counter for every table, there's no code that checks whether the number should go down or not (it's a waste of resources) - it only goes up, regardless of whether query is successful or not.

This approach guarantees:

1. performance - no need to worry about what the state of counter should be (whether it should go down or not)
2. uniqueness - this is the fastest and most secure way to calculate a unique identifier for a row - just increment a number by `auto_increment_offset`. No need to worry about collisions and what not. You are 100% certain that if you increment the last number by `auto_increment_offset` - you're getting a new, unique and unused number in your database/

With databases, and MySQL especially - there are various factors when it comes to write or read performance. Min-maxing and trying to fiddle with `auto_increment` is not one of those. You'll be fine if you leave everything as is.

If you think you'll exceed the maximum of a 4-byte unsigned integer (around 4.2 billion), you can consider changing your primary key to a `bigint`. You won't exceed that for a few thousand years if you were to insert thousands of records per second.